# What techniques to use for server side data reception of large-scale mobile app

Tags: ios

Fellow StackOverflowers,

we are building an iOS application that will record data which will have to be sent back to our server at certain times. The server will not be sending back any data to the client, other than confirmation that the data has been received successfully. Processing load on the server may become an issue, so we want to design our server/client communication such that overhead is kept as low as possible.

1) Would it be wise to use PHP to write the received data to filesystem/database? It's easy and maintainable, but may be a lot less efficient than, for example, a Java application in Glassfish (or a 'hand-coded' server daemon in C if we choose the raw socket connection).

2) Would it be wise to write the received data directly to the MySQL database (running on the same server), or do you think we should write the data to filesystem first and parse it to a database asynchronously to the reception of the data (i.e., at a time when the server has resources to spare)

3) Which seems wiser: to use a protocol such as HTTP or FTP, or to build our own server daemon and have the clients connect to a socket and push data over it like in this heavily simplified example:

```
SocketFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
write(SocketFD, theData, sizeOfTheData);
```

Or, as Krumelur points out, maybe this is a non-issue with regard to server load?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see the issue. If many users hit your server, it will become slow. I can't see how the used transfer protocol could have a big influence on reducing CPU load? Do you want to AVOID that many users at the same time bring the CPU up? If yes, then throttle them or answer your client to retry in x minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to all three these questions depends on your budget and how serious the load will be.

1. I think php isn't a wise choice. If you have the time and skill to write something in C or C++ or something, I'd recommend doing that. Especially because that would provide thread control. If you're budget doesn't reach that far, Java, as you suggested, would be a good option, or maybe Ruby or Python.
2. I would suggest using sqlite for storing the data in the app. If only part of the data is send and you can keep that part separate from the rest, consider putting all that data in a separate sqlite db. You can than send that entire file. If you need just a part of the data and are concerned with the server load so much, than I guess you have two options. Ether let the app create a sqlite file with all data to transfer and send that file. Or just send a serialized array.

   On first thought I'd say you should use a sqlite db on the server side too, to ease the process of parsing from incoming data to db. On second thought that's a bad idea since sqlite doesn't support multithreading, and if you're load is going to be so huge that's not desirable.
3. Why not use websockets? There are daemons available in most languages. You could open a socket with every client that wishes to send data, than give a green light "send it now" whenever a thread for processing comes available. After the trafic is complete you dispose the connection. But this would only be efficient if the number of requests is so huge the server has to handle rescheduling so much that it would take more cpu than just do what Krumelur sugests.

I wonder what you're building, and how it will be producing such a massive server load!